# How to use phonegap to be part of whole native ios application

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am with ios, I have a NavigationController with many child views.

I'd like to mix PhoneGap in, to create a new UIViewController with a webview inside, and use PhoneGap technology in this UIViewController.

I read the PhoneGap docs, only found that I need to use PhoneGap application-wide, to build the app from scratch, that is not what I need.

How to do that?

Comment: will you please elaborate the question.

Comment: no clear cut question who vote this

Comment: I think this will helpful. Try this: http://www.nsbasic.com/app/tutorials/TT11.htm

Comment: What do you want to do? What is the functionality that you need from the part that you wish to use phonegap for? Technically there is nothing that cannot be done with a webview. You can pick a few classes from Phonegap that would get your job done.

Answer (score 1):

Use PhoneGapViewController instead of UIViewController